# Когда выбрасывать исключение, а когда возвращать объект результата (с ошибкой)?

Tags: php

Часто в методы классов должны вернуть информацию об успешной операции.

Например, добавление товара в корзину, `addProduct2Basket(int $productId, int $quantity = 1)` - при успешном добавлении, достаточно получить булево значение - true.Я
А если товара нет в каталоге ? Выбрасывать исключение ? Потом его перехватывать и обрабатывать.. ?
Хочется также, чтобы метод вернул ошибку, например для записи в лог.
Чтобы метод не возвращал разные типы данных, с начало булево, потом строка ошибки..

Наверное, хорошо бы завести класс `Result`, который имеет метод `success()` и `getErrorMessages()`, который возвращает инфу об ошибке при `success() === false`.

Как все таки лучше делать ? Какие есть варианты ?
Стоит ли часто использовать для разных методов такой подход - возвращения объекта результата ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала разберемся в определениях:

**Ошибки (ErrorException)** - это ситуации, которые невозможно обработать, их выбрасывает сам php если не может совершить операцию. Вы не должны выбрасывать их из кода. Все что вы можете сделать при обработке такой ситуации - показать пользователю страницу с извинениями, сделать запись в лог и отправить сообщение на почту с сообщением об ошибке.

**Исключения (Exceptions)** - это способы управления потоком вашего приложения: т.е. если вы делаете валидацию чего либо и нашли ошибку в данных, то смело можно выбрасывать ValidationException.

Аналогично, на вашем примере, в случае если вы не нашли товар в каталоге, то можно выкинуть NotFoundException c кодом 404. Реализовать такое можно таким образом:

```
class NotFoundException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct($message = "Not found", $code = 404)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }
}
```

При желании можно передавать кастомное сообщение прямо при вызове исключения, чтобы указать на конкретную ошибку:

```
throw new NotFoundException('Item not found');
```

Так же, если вы хотите обрабатывать ошибки/исключения, вам понадобится соответствующий обработчик. Если вы используете какой-либо фреймворк, то рекомендую обратится к его документации. Как правило, фреймворки из коробки предоставляют инструментарий обработки исключений/ошибок. Для чистого php (и просто для общего понимания как это работает) рекомендую вам обратить внимание на эту [страницу документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.errorfunc.php), а особенно [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) и [set_exception_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php).

Что касается возвращения "результата-объекта" - это регламентируется только авторами приложения, если вам необходимо вернуть какую-то доп. информацию о добавленном/обновленном/удаленном объекте, то в этом нет ничего страшного. Аналогично, если вы просто вернете какой-либо флаг, что операция выполнена успешно, но не вернете доп. информацию, в этом тоже нет ничего плохого. Данную информацию вы добавляете для дальнейшей обработки, если она не нужна, следовательно и возвращать данные не обязательно.

Comment: Спасибо!

По поводу исключений:
в одном из проектов, я решил придерживаться способу выбрасывания исключений, в таких случаях, как:
- не открывается файл для чтения (при импорте данных), 
- при импорте товара не указаны обязательные поля,  
- при сохранении в бд произошла ошибка, и т.д.

В результате, у меня появилась директория `Exceptions/` где было несколько десятков типов исключений:

`Exceptions\BaseException`, `Exceptions\BaseException`, `Exceptions\Import\NoFoundFileException`, и т.д.

Comment: Это было удобно с точки зрения отлавливания любого типа исключения, и обработки (запись в лог, оповещения и т.п.).

Но меня смутило то, что на каждый новый класс (функционал) у меня появлялся новый тип исключения.

И скорее всего проблема в том, что у меня нет точного понимания, в каких случаях лучше выбрасывать исключение, а в каких стоит иное решение применять - но какое ?

Даже когда на github смотрю, популярные решения, у них там на всю библиотеку используется 2-3 типа исключения..

Comment: @samiy-slavniy Я думаю, что решения на github, которые вы смотрели, возможно и не требовали большого кол-ва типов исключений. Все-таки, мне кажется, что решения по разделения исключений тоже остаются за создателем программы, так как нет какого-то особенного регламента на эту тему. Если вам кажется, что у вас слишком много типов исключений, то возможно вам следует просто объединить сгруппировав по типу некоторые из них, но выбрасывать с разными сообщениями и данными о событии.